# Questions about django's user API (user id)

Tags: django, concurrency

I'm looking at Django's built in implementation of users, and have a few questions

1. What's the right way to identify users? Username are unique - so that could be an identifier, but they're easily changable (u.username = 'somethingelse', u.save()). Googling finds a `id` field, but why is that not in the docs (a mistake, or am I not supposed to use it?)
2. How can I make the user id auto increment? Somewhere in the docs it recommends not deleting users, but I like letting users delete their info if they want to. I checked - and when deleting a user the user id is freed
3. How does Django do concurrency? There are a couple threads on this about how to make your own queries concurrent-proof, but I didn't find anything on whether Django's built in classes (e.g. users) are concurrent. For example, is it possible that two users can register with the same username at the same time? That's a relatively simple example, as the table could be generated with a plain old constraint, but what about more complex cases (updating permissions?) that should(?) use transactions?
4. Does django do "on delete cascade"? Back to question 2, if I delete a user, and everything related to that user id is deleted, off the top of my head I think it's okay if someone else gets the same id (might be confusing if someone bookmarks a page with the user id and now it's a new user)

Example code of user being deleted and reusing the ID (in the django shell)

```
userA = User.objects.create_user('userA')
userA.id # (prints 2 for example)
# I go to the admin page, I see the new user
userA.delete()
# Admin page, userA gone
userB = User.objects.create_user('userB')
userB.id # (prints 2 again)
# UserB is visible in the admin page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting at the wrong place. If you want to know how Django models work, you should be reading the tutorial and the models documentation, not the authentication docs, which naturally miss out all the stuff that is not specific to the users model. There is an autoincrementing id field for every Django model, as explained in those model docs.

I doubt that the docs state you shouldn't delete users. And I don't understand the relevance of there now being a "free" id when the user is deleted. That ID is of course not reused, because the db autoincrement has moved on. This is basic to how RDBMSs work.

Concurrency and transactions, naturally, are covered in the transactions docs.

**Edit**

I've edited Daniel's answer to include a few things he didn't answer (but after looking at the general django models documentation as he said I did learn a lot - didn't realize Django's users are just built on its models API).

1. All models define an autoincrementing primary key integer id field. That's the best way to identifier users. And as with all other models, you could search by other columns too.
2. I definitely saw somewhere in the docs where it recommended not deleting users (because I carefully read it several times - it was surprising), though I haven't seen it since. Maybe it was removed in a later version or something. The strange **behaviour where deleted ids were reuused is unique to sqlite**. It doesn't happen with say MySQL or Postgresql etc. Don't remember if the ids are reused only when the deleted id was the previously max value, or if they're always reused (i.e. pick the lowest value not currently assigned to a row)
3. Django has a [transactions interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) that lets you control transactions/savepoints/autocommit mode. It even has support for `select ... for update` when you're making queries
4. Django has support for [`on delete ...`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#arguments). **However** this is enforced at Django's level. If you inspect the generated sql queries for creating tables you will notice that it doesn't do `on delete ...` there. See [Django not setting MySQL ON DELETE = CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670920/django-not-setting-mysql-on-delete-cascade)

Comment: Argh, I can't find the link anymore, but I definitely read something in the docs (official or the django book, they're both green-themed) about recommending to set the user as inactive instead of deleting them, as to maintain foreign keys, which is what got me worried about maintaining that data integrity. Also, the ID is reuused when I delete a user, at least when I tried it just now (example in the question). I'll check out the general model docs - thanks for the pointer

Comment: Then there is clearly something very weird about your database setup. That should definitely never happen, for obvious reasons of database integrity. The id field is an autoincrement, and setting new values is taken care of by the database, not by Django.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that you are probably using SQLite as your db, which can reuse deleted ids. If this is a concern, you should probably use a proper db, such as PostgreSQL, especially as you will almost certainly be doing so when deployed.

Comment: Ah yeah, I realized that yesterday too (but didn't get a chance to update the question) (I am using sqlite for development - just playing around). However, I thought sqlite does keep autoincrementing if you do `integer primary key autoincrement` it won't reuse ids? http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1 Or is that not built into django (it doesn't generate the primary key autoincrement for sqlite so that keys aren't reused). I'm doing some more research on models and if that answers my questions I'll accept this answer