# Why does Django only emulate ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, foreign-keys, cascade

I recently learned that [Django's on_delete=CASCADE only emulates ON DELETE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670920/django-not-setting-mysql-on-delete-cascade) -- if I run a `DELETE FROM ParentTable` as explicit SQL, it will fail when the child table's rows have live foreign keys to the parent.

Why is Django designed this way? Why does it reproduce this behaviour in the Python layer when it could more easily add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the table in the database itself?

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not part of their team, I think there is 2 main reasons why Django devs implemented it that way.

1) **Compatibility**

It is logic to implement this kind of mechanic in the ORM since it allows easier supporting towards multiples databases types.

2) **App notification**

By implementing their own Cascade logic their able to know when and how data is deleted in the related database. This is relevant especially considering how Django works.